# how to fetch id from the database of the selected item in listview

Tags: uwp

I am trying to fetch the id from the database of the clicked item. What I have to do to fetch the id of the clicked item in list view. It is showing zero as value and how to get description according to that id from database.

```
namespace javalearningapp_v1 {
    public sealed partial class tutorial: Page {
        string path;
        SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection conn;
        private List < tutoriallistdb > listOfStudents = new List < tutoriallistdb > ();
        public tutorial() {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            path = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "java2db.sqlite");
            conn = new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), path);
            conn.CreateTable < tutoriallistdb > ();
            Retrieve();
        }
        public class tutoriallistdb {
            [PrimaryKey]
            public Int32 sno {
                get;
                set;
            }
            public string lname {
                get;
                set;
            }
            public string description {
                get;
                set;
            }
        }

        private void Retrieve() {
            var query = conn.Table < tutoriallistdb > ();
            string name = "";

            foreach(var message in query) {
                name = message.lname;
                listOfStudents.Add(new tutoriallistdb {
                    lname = name
                });

            }
            tutoriallist.ItemsSource = listOfStudents;

        }

        private void tutoriallist_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e) {
            tutoriallistdb item = (tutoriallistdb) e.ClickedItem;
            var desc = conn.Query < tutoriallistdb > ("select description from tutoriallistdb where sno=?", a.sno);
            Frame.Navigate(typeof(tutdesc), desc);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> var desc = conn.Query < tutoriallistdb > ("select description from tutoriallistdb where sno=?", a.sno);

The issue seems to be related with the type of parameters you passed. For the `Sql` sentence, I suggested you passing a string type parameter.

**Usage**

```
private void tutoriallist_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    tutoriallistdb item = (tutoriallistdb)e.ClickedItem;
    var desc = conn.Query<tutoriallistdb>("select description from tutoriallistdb where sno=?", item.sno.ToString());
    Frame.Navigate(typeof(tutdesc), desc);
}
```

**PS**
 I found a wrong logic in your code.

```
foreach (var message in query)
{
    name = message.lname;
    listOfStudents.Add(new tutoriallistdb { lname = name});
}
tutoriallist.ItemsSource = listOfStudents;
```

The sno attribute of this item in the `tutoriallist` is not assigned. it is
 always zero. So you can query only one same data where `sno` is zero.

**Modify**

```
foreach (var message in query)
  {
      name = message.lname;
      listOfStudents.Add(new tutoriallistdb { lname = name , sno = message.sno });
  }
  tutoriallist.ItemsSource = listOfStudents;
```